# Laravel Mail editor package return and error Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

### Describe the bug

`Too few arguments to function App\Mail\ChangeEmailRequest::__construct(), 0 passed in D:\Laravel\grand\grandcalendar-api\vendor\qoraiche\laravel-mail-editor\src\MailEclipse.php on line 796 and exactly 2 expected`

I got this error after installed the package from the old mails

### Reproduction steps

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. installed the app
2. Go to `/maileclipse/mailables`
3. then error fetched

### Laravel Version:

9.19

```
"php": "^8.0.2",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
"intervention/image": "^2.7",
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
"laravel/horizon": "^5.14",
"laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
"laravel/telescope": "^4.13",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.0",
"paytabscom/laravel_paytabs": "^1.4",
"predis/predis": "~1.0",
"qoraiche/laravel-mail-editor": "^4.0",
"spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^4.7",
```

### MailEclipse package version:

MailEclipse: 4.0

### Screenshots

[image]

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ChangeEmailRequest extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $otp;
    public $userName;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($otp, $userName)
    {
        $this->otp = $otp;
        $this->userName = $userName;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope
     */
    public function envelope()
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'Verify Change Email Request with OTP ',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content
     */
    public function content()
    {
        return new Content(
            markdown: 'emails.users.changeEmailRequest',
            with: [
                'otp' => $this->otp,
                'userName' => $this->userName,
            ],
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attachments()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

But if I add null to construct variable, it works

```
/**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($otp = null, $userName= null)
    {
        $this->otp = $otp;
        $this->userName = $userName;
    }
```

I am using this package: https://github.com/Qoraiche/laravel-mail-editor

Comment: You don't show any code creating this object, but the error is very clear. You aren't passing any arguments when creating it.

Comment: This package call all classes in side App\Mail so when this package call it without path any params maybe this is from the package itself